# Admin: Displaying IntegerField with not predefined choices as select with options

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with GenericForeignKey:

```
class Breadcrumbs( models.Model ):

    title = models.CharField( max_length = 256 )

    limit = models.Q( app_label = 'news', model = 'NewsPost' )

    content_type = models.ForeignKey( ContentType, limit_choices_to = limit )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey( 'content_type', 'object_id' )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'breadcrumbs'
```

By default there is an input text widget for object_id:

[image]

How to make it as select with options? Also I would like to fill it with NewsPost ids (or with **unicode**() of NewsPost) by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `PositiveIntegerField` here. You should use a `ForeignKey` to `NewsPost`.

This will do the two things you need with no additional effort.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I would like to point to objects of another models in the future.

Comment: @sergzach I'm not sure making things more complicated right now is going to make things a lot easier in the future anyway. As such, you should just do a (probably two) database migrations in the future, when you decide to change your datamodel. There might be considerations I'm missing here, but you'll need to tell us more if you want a more in-depth response.